# Object is not a member of package - No SBT, Using IntelliJ

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

Project Structure

```
/
first
--- build
    --- common
        --- java
            --- com.mypackage.firsts
                --- file1_1.java
                --- file2_1.java
second
--- src
    --- main
        --- scala
            --- com.mypackage.seconds
                --- file2_1.scala
                --- file2_1.scala
```

`file2_1.java` imports `file1_1.java` as follows `import com.mypackage.firsts.file1_1`. IntelliJ allows me to use the auto-complete feature to fill out that import just fine. However, when compiling (this project does not use sbt) I get the following error

```
object firsts is not a member of package com.impact
    import com.impact.firsts.file1_1
```

How can I solve this issue? The `java` directory above is marked as a `source root`.

Comment: What are you using to compile the project? Can you share exactly what you do to get it compiled? Also, do you have a folder `common` with a child folder `mypackage` with a children folder `firsts`? And why are you keeping `.java` files inside the scala folder?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly there's not a lot I can share, but a few things if not all are handled by gradle

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly I edited my post. There is indeed `.scala` files in the scala folder and I correctly changed the project structure, `common/java/com/mypackage/firsts`

Comment: I suggest that you take take the time to create a [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Chances are that you will figure out what's wrong as part of the process. Otherwise, you will have something more concrete to share in your question. Without at least a simplified (but functional) gradle build definition and the contents of the source files people can't do much to help you other than guess what the problem may be.

Comment: @it2901  If you're managing the while project with IntelliJ (without build tools) then look `File -> Project Structure`.

Comment: @it2901 *"a few things if not all are handled by gradle"* If you're already using Gradle, why not to organize your project according to [standard directory structure](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html) so that you'll not rely on marking directories as source roots in IntelliJ? Try to manage the whole your project with your build tool (Gradle, Maven, sbt etc.). I suspect that if you manage it partially with a build tool, partially with IntelliJ, this can confuse IntelliJ.